# C++ template construction for class member lists

Tags: c++, templates

So I have made a little bit of C++ templates before: some quite basic examples of the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) for classes of mathematical numbers. This time I tried using the same pattern to create a list or "network" for objects of a class which they could add themselves to and look around for other objects. I thought I could use a static std::list to do this. So my attempt goes like this:

```
template<class C> class HasNetwork{
  public:
  HasNetwork(){}
  static list<C*> m;
};
template<class C> list<C*> HasNetwork<C>::m = list<C*>();
class IHaveNetwork: public HasNetwork<IHaveNetwork>{
  public:
  IHaveNetwork(){ m.push_back(this); }
};
int main(){
  IHaveNetwork lHF, lHF2;
  //for(list<IHaveNetwork*>::iterator it = lHF.m->begin();  ; it++);
  return 0;
}
```

It seems to compile, but I get nasty link errors ( even with the for loop iterator commented out ). Maybe I need to do some cast or maybe "this" is not defined until after the constructor finishes?

Here is the link error:

```
/tmp/templatest-912860.o: In function `__clang_call_terminate':
templatest.cpp:

(.text.__clang_call_terminate[__clang_call_terminate]+0x9): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'


templatest.cpp:(.text.__clang_call_terminate[__clang_call_terminate]+0x12): undefined reference to `std::terminate()'


/tmp/templatest-912860.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_List_node<IHaveNetwork*> 

>::deallocate(std::_List_node<IHaveNetwork*>*, unsigned long)':
```

templatest.cpp:

```
 (.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt10_List_nodeIP12IHaveNetworkEE10deallocateEPS4_m[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt10_List_nodeIP12IHaveNetworkEE10deallocateEPS4_m]+0x1c): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'

/tmp/templatest-912860.o: In function `std::list<IHaveNetwork*, std::allocator<IHaveNetwork*> 

>::_M_insert(std::_List_iterator<IHaveNetwork*>, IHaveNetwork* const&)':
```

templatest.cpp:

```
(.text._ZNSt4listIP12IHaveNetworkSaIS1_EE9_M_insertESt14_List_iteratorIS1_ERKS1_[_ZNSt4listIP12IHaveNetworkSaIS1_EE9_M_insertESt14_List_iteratorIS1_ERKS1_]+0x31): undefined reference to 

`std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
```

/tmp/templatest-912860.o: In function `std::list >::_M_create_node(IHaveNetwork* const&)':
templatest.cpp:

```
(.text._ZNSt4listIP12IHaveNetworkSaIS1_EE14_M_create_nodeERKS1_[_ZNSt4listIP12IHaveNetworkSaIS1_EE14_M_create_nodeERKS1_]+0xa0): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'

templatest.cpp:(.text._ZNSt4listIP12IHaveNetworkSaIS1_EE14_M_create_nodeERKS1_[_ZNSt4listIP12IHaveNetworkSaIS1_EE14_M_create_nodeERKS1_]+0xbb): undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
templatest.cpp:    

(.text._ZNSt4listIP12IHaveNetworkSaIS1_EE14_M_create_nodeERKS1_[_ZNSt4listIP12IHaveNetworkSaIS1_EE14_M_create_nodeERKS1_]+0xce): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'

/tmp/templatest-912860.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_List_node<IHaveNetwork*> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)':

templatest.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt10_List_nodeIP12IHaveNetworkEE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt10_List_nodeIP12IHaveNetworkEE8allocateEmPKv]+0x33): undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_alloc()'

templatest.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt10_List_nodeIP12IHaveNetworkEE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt10_List_nodeIP12IHaveNetworkEE8allocateEmPKv]+0x40): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
```

/tmp/templatest-912860.o:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'

Comment: darn I was about to upvote you for the help, sorry for the typo man.

Comment: I tried it [here](http://rextester.com/BDJL98512) seems be fine.

Comment: Yes it compiles fine but does not link. Maybe I need to link in list somehow?

Comment: What's the link error?

Comment: sorry I'm struggling trying to learn how to format  these beasts so it's readable in the question.

Comment: It seems has nothing to do with your code, might be a link issue.

Comment: It works for me: http://ideone.com/uBE7Ms

Comment: Yes you are right, I have probably been compiling too much c so I used gcc instead of g++ and then got link errors. With g++ works fine. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce.

Here is a slightly modified version of you code that compiles links and runs without even a warning (I only had to fix some indirection level errors):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

template<class C> class HasNetwork{
  public:
  HasNetwork(){}
  static std::list<C*> m;
};
template<class C> std::list<C*> HasNetwork<C>::m = std::list<C*>();
class IHaveNetwork: public HasNetwork<IHaveNetwork>{
    std::string name;
  public:
      IHaveNetwork(const std::string &name): name(name) { m.push_back(this); }
      std::string getName() const {
          return name;
      }
};
int main(){
  IHaveNetwork lHF("foo"), lHF2("bar");
  for(std::list<IHaveNetwork*>::iterator it = lHF.m.begin();  it != lHF.m.end(); it++) {
      std::cout << (*it)->getName() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What line do you run for compiling and linking?

Comment: argh nooo, I was using gcc instead of g++, embarrasing. now your code works perfectly. thanks alot for the help.